# javascript string formation error

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a javascript string and am running into syntax errors. What's the best way to put it?

```
'statement:'+var1+'<br /><table><thead><tr><th>head1</th><th>head2</th><th>head3</th></tr></thead><tbody>'+$.each(element,function(j){+'<tr><td>'+element[j][0]+'</td><td>'+element[j][1]+'</td><td>'+element[j][2]+'</td></tr>'+});+'</tbody></table>'
```

Where element is a json ojbect.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". Is it an object? Your problem is here: `+});` ... what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the string and then later manipulate it with the `each()` function:

```
var string = 'statement:' + var1 + '<br /><table><thead><tr><th>head1</th><th>head2</th><th>head3</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
$.each(element,function(j){
    string += '<tr><td>'+element[j][0]+'</td><td>'+element[j][1]+'</td><td>'+element[j][2]+'</td></tr>'
});
string += '</tbody></table>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do too many stuffs in a single line of code?

```
var txt = 'statement:'+var1+'<br /><table><thead><tr><th>head1</th><th>head2</th>    <th>head3</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

$.each(element,function(j){+
    txt += '<tr><td>'+element[j][0]+'</td><td>'+element[j][1]+
    '</td><td>'+element[j][2]+'</td></tr>';
});

txt +='</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: it's a convenience thing. That's it. Jeff's comment helped.